# How to display product name in form

Tags: google-app-engine, referenceproperty

model.py

```
class Product(db.Model):
    product_name_jp = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    product_code = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class ProductPrice(db.Model):
    product = db.ReferenceProperty(Product,
                                   collection_name='price_collection')
    quantity = db.IntegerProperty()
    price = db.IntegerProperty()
```

forms.py

```
class ProductPriceForm(forms.Form):
    f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name")
    f_quantity = forms.TextField("Quantity ", required=True)
    f_price = forms.TextField("Price ", required=True)
```

views.py

```
def addproductprice(request):
    productprice_form = ProductPriceForm()



    if request.method =="POST" and productprice_form.validate(request.form):

        productprice_form.save()

    return render_to_response('myapp/message.html',{'form':productprice_form.as_widget(), 'message':'Insert Produce Price xxx '})
```

Resuls is

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/StackOverFlow/2.JPG

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27576887/StackOverFlow/3.jpg

My question: How to display the product_name_jp instead of "myapp.models.Product object at xxx"

Thanks

Comment: How is `ModelField` defined?

Comment: I am using Kay Framework and I dont have any idea what is ModelField. Could you please see http://kay-docs.shehas.net/1.0.0/forms_reference.html#module-kay.utils.forms for ModelFielf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [the docs](http://kay-docs.shehas.net/1.0.0/forms_reference.html#kay.utils.forms.Field), under *class kay.utils.forms.ModelField*:

> If the Model class has `__unicode__()` method, the return value of this
>   method will be used for rendering the text in an option tag. If
>   there’s no `__unicode__()` method, `Model.__repr__()` will be used for
>   this purpose.
>
> You can override this behavior by passing an attribute
>   name used for the option tag’s value with option_name keyword argument
>   on initialization of this field.

That tells us you need to set the `option_name` keyword in this line

```
f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name")
```

It's not documented very well so I can't tell you exactly how to do that, could be one of the following

```
f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name", option_name=Product.product_name_jp)
```

or

```
f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name", option_name='product_name_jp')
```

or

```
f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name", option_name=Product._properties['product_name_jp'])
```

Perhaps something other than the ones I've suggested, I'm not sure, but you will probably find out by trying a couple.

---

**Edit:**

As mentiond by John in the comments, this was the one that worked

```
f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name", option_name='product_name_jp')
```

Comment: f_product = forms.ModelField(model=Product, default=None, label="Product Name", option_name='product_name_jp') is correct. Thanks a lot